# Rxjs How to wait for all observables from dynamic components to complete in smart component

Tags: angular, highcharts, rxjs

Hellow,

In my project I want to make an export (PDF) by clicking on a button on the page. In my page I have a dashboard which creates multiple charts dynamically. When I click on the "export" button I want to inform each dynamic component to create an svg from the current chart instance and pass it to the "page" component. In order to be able to create an svg I have to wait until an instance of the chart is created. When I have all the svg's from the different dynamic components I am able to pass the info (different svg's) to the body of an api call which will create a pdf.

So I tried to achieve this in a [test project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-zpm3wh). I don't know the correct approach so I tried to fill an array from the service with observables in the dynamic components.

The problem that I have is how will I know that all the observables (which returns SVG's or error when it fails) from the dynamic components are added to the array before doing a forkjoin in the *landing-page* component. My forkJoin also doesn't return the svg's so I do something wrong. But maybe there is a better approach to wait for all dynamic Components until they created their svg's.

Comment: All your dynamic components are subscribed to `clickExportPdfStream` event which is called synchronously so they will be all in that array

Comment: This question (and its answers) would be much better if the code under examination was on this site instead of hidden on another site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that when `chartInstanceStream$` emits, it has no subscribers, meaning that it can't complete due to `first()`, which also means that `forkJoin` won't emit unless all the provided observables emitted at lest once and completed.

`chartInstanceStream$` emits due to `setChartInstance`, which happens before `testService.clickExportPdfStream` emits.

One quick fix would be to turn `chartInstanceStream` into a `ReplaySubject` so that it will *replay* its latest value(s) to the *late subscribers*.

So, from this:

```js
chartInstanceStream$ = new Subject<Highcharts.Chart>();
```

to this:

```js
chartInstanceStream$ = new ReplaySubject<Highcharts.Chart>(1);
```

`forkJoin` internally subscribes to all the provided observables. By converting `chartInstanceStream$` into a `ReplaySubject`, you're making sure that the late subscribers(those from `forkJoin`) will receive the oldest value emitted by `ReplaySubject`.

And because your observables which `forkJoin` subscribes to look like this:

```js
this.chartInstanceStream$.pipe(
    map((chart: Highcharts.Chart) =>
      chart.getSVG()
    ),
    first() // !
  )
```

after they emit one value, they will immediately complete as well, due to `first()`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using service as you did is one approach.

Another solution for this might be exporting a `public` function from the dynamic component, and then call them from your parent component.

For example, I have this simple `ChartComponent` that mimics svg export:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./chart.component.css"]
})
export class ChartComponent {
  exportSvg(): Observable<string> {
    return defer(() => 
      timer(Math.random() * 2000 + 500).pipe(mapTo('svg'))
    )
  }
}
```

Now in my parent component I am querying those components and calling `exportSvg` on demand:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ChartComponent) charts: QueryList<ChartComponent>;

  onExportClick(): void {
    const charts = this.charts.map(component => component.exportSvg());

    forkJoin(charts).subscribe(console.log)
  }
}
```

In my example I didn't create the `ChartComponent`s dynamically, but it should behave the same way.

Full example can be found in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zruhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)